# Use custom claims in React js to render different UI

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase-authentication

In my React web application I have normal users and I have admin users. I want to show different UI for admin users with the help of custom claims.

In my `authContext` component I want to set the `IdTokenResults.claims.admin` to an user.admin:

```
export const AuthContextProvider: React.FunctionComponent<IProps> = ({
  children,
}) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(authReducer, {
    user: null,
    authIsReacdy: false,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsub = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      user?.getIdTokenResult().then((idTokenResult) => {
        console.log(idTokenResult.claims);
        user.admin = idTokenResult.claims.admin;
      });
      dispatch({ type: "AUTH_IS_READY", payload: user });
      unsub();
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ ...state, dispatch }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Unfortunately, I got an error that Property 'admin' does not exist on type 'User'. Even though I've added it to the type as you can see:

```
export type Dispatch = (action: any) => void;
type User = {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  displayName: string;
  uid: string;
  username: string;
  admin: boolean;
};

export const AuthContext = createContext<
  { dispatch: Dispatch; user: User } | undefined
>(undefined);

export const authReducer = (state: any, action: any) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LOGIN":
      return { ...state, user: action.payload };
    case "LOGOUT":
      return { ...state, user: null };
    case "AUTH_IS_READY":
      return { ...state, user: action.payload, authIsReady: true };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: What is the content of authReducer ?

Comment: I've updated the question to show the content of the authReducer

Comment: `getIdTokenResult` doesn't exist either so I guess it's not the same user

Comment: Can you show how you set the claims?

Comment: @JosineD58 I think the problem is that you are setting the admin property to a firebase User type : https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#properties_1 which doesn't exist.